# How to import all data in excel and every 5 min excel sheet update?

Tags: sql, excel

i want to import tables data into excel sheet and excel sheet update every time when modification made in tables data . because user want , not download every time new  excel sheet ?

Comment: Once the Excel File get Download it will disconnect from the internet and i don't think that there is any way to refresh Data in Excel. You have to Download every Time by manually or by forcefully in such timeframe..

Comment: This is not answering your question but IMO, if the user wants 'live' data, present it on a web page (show the age of the data or time stamp). You can also show a button like 'Download excel' to get the excel version. But most important, ask the user what he/she wants to do, often there are other solutions to consider. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - open excel and create connection to `Sql Server`

[image]

**Step 2** - at the end `create connection wizard` inserts data from the table inside the selected sheet

[image]

**Step 3** - after all you can go to the Data->Connections->Select your connection->Properties and there will be possible to change refresh interval

[image]